# Custom sort of List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting, custom-sort

I have a `List<string>`, where the entries are locations, like "010101", "010102", "010201", ..., with following meaning:

- First two characters : floor
- Next two characters : lane
- Last two characters : entry in lane

Normal sorting reveals a list like the following:

```
010101
010102
010103
010201
010202
020101
020102
020201
020202
020203
020204
...
```

I would like a custom sorting, where:

- on floor "01", the sorting is done in a normal way:

  ```
    010101
    010102
    010103
    010201
    010202
  ```
- on floor "02", the sorting is done in a reversed way for the lane, but not for the entry in lane, so something like:

  ```
    ...
    020201
    020202
    020203
    020204
    020101
    020102
  ```

Here on the site, I've found the `IEnumerable` as a solution, but this only works for `List<T>` where `T` is a new class. This is not relevant here, as I'm dealing with "simple" strings.
I've also found the `Enumerable` as a solution, but this also doesn't work, because the list of possible strings is far too large (not enumerable) and I'd prefer a flexible solution.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement `IComparer<string>` (or a `Comparison<string>` delegate) and pass that to a call to `List<T>.Sort`. It's hard to know what you mean by "the `IEnumerable` as a solution" - `IEnumerable` is just an interface. (Likewise "I've also found the `Enumerable` as a solution" - that's just a class containing extension methods.) Fundamentally I suspect you'd be best off defining a class to represent the information in the strings, and parsing before sorting, but that's a slightly different matter - the more immediate problem is that your question is very unclear.

Comment: I mean that I have been searching on the site here for a solution. The solutions I found were not applicable, either because I can't create a new class, either because my number of strings is that high that I can't go for the `Enumerable` approach.

Comment: Your description of the solutions is so vague that we really can't tell whether they're a reasonable starting point or not. We don't know what you mean by "the Enumerable approach" - or what your requirements are. (How many strings, and what goes wrong when you try whatever it is that you're calling "the Enumerable approach"?)

Comment: I have found a post of a person, trying to customsort the list "C", "D", "G", "T" as "D", "G", "T", "C". In order to do that, an `Enumerable` was created, based on those four characters. This approach (which I call the `Enumerable` approach) is not possible here, as the number of possible strings is too large.

Comment: No, an instance of `Enumerable` was certainly *not* created, because [`Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-8.0) is a static class. Are you aware that `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<string>`? It's still unclear whether or not you've tried to provide a custom comparison to `List<T>.Sort`, to be honest...

Comment: Are there more than two floors?

Comment: @Enigmativity: No, there are just two, hence the answer from Stephan Bauer is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve the desired behavior, e.g. using a [`Comparison<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1):

```
var input = new List<string>() { "010101", "010102", "010103", "010201", "010202", "020101", "020102", "020201", "020202", "020203", "020204" };

Comparison<string> comparison = (s1, s2) =>
{
    if (s1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s1));
    if (s2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s2));
    if (s1.Length != 6 || s2.Length != 6) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    // Compare floor (first 2 digits)
    var floor1 = s1.Substring(0, 2);
    var floor2 = s2.Substring(0, 2);
    var result = floor1.CompareTo(floor2);
    if (result != 0) return result;

    // Compare lane (middle 2 digits)
    var lane1 = s1.Substring(2, 2);
    var lane2 = s2.Substring(2, 2);
    // Special case: in floor 02, reverse order of lanes
    result = floor1 == "02"
       ? lane2.CompareTo(lane1) 
       : lane1.CompareTo(lane2);
    if (result != 0) return result;

    // Compare entry (last 2 digits)
    return s1.Substring(4, 2).CompareTo(s2.Substring(4, 2));
};

// Sort the list using the comparison defined before
input.Sort(comparison);
```

Comment: This approach works great for sorting strings, but the problem presented seems like it would be better solved by using an object to keep track of the floor, lane, and entry in lane. It would also be easier to manipulate those fields and the result would override .ToString to present however they want.

Comment: It's not a good idea to return `-result` to reverse the result - if `result` is `int.MinValue`, then `-result` will *also* be `int.MinValue`. The simplest robust change is probably `return -Math.Sign(result)`. An alternative would be to use `result = floor1 == "02"?  lane2.CompareTo(lane1) : lane1.CompareTo(lane2);`

Answer (score 1):

If your input is nicely curated (i.e. all numerals and all 6 characters) then this is a simple way to do it:

```
var input = new List<string>()
{
    "010101", "010102", "010103", "010201", "010202",
    "020101", "020102", "020201", "020202", "020203", "020204"
};

var output =
    input
        .Select(x => new
        {
            location = x,
            floor = int.Parse(x.Substring(0, 2)),
            lane = int.Parse(x.Substring(2, 2)),
            entry = int.Parse(x.Substring(4, 2))
        })
        .OrderBy(x =>
            x.floor * 10000
            + (x.floor % 2 == 0 ? 99 - x.lane : x.lane) * 100
            + x.entry)
        .Select(x => x.location)
        .ToList();
```

That produces:

```
010101 
010102 
010103 
010201 
010202 
020201 
020202 
020203 
020204 
020101 
020102
```

Comment: Your answer is an excellent extension, based on odd/even floor numbers. Thanks.