# How to use custom sorting, based on the "Sort()" method of List<OwnObject>

Tags: c#, list, sorting, custom-sort

In [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76032253/custom-sort-of-liststring), I wanted to custom order a list of strings (`List<string>`). This is working fine now.

Now I would like a step further and sort a list of objects, having the mentioned strings as their name.

I thought this might be easy:

```
public class OwnObject : IComparable
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is OwnObject)) return 0;

        string s1 = this.Name;
        string s2 = (obj as OwnObject).Name;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

... and in another file, do something like:

```
...ToList().Sort(OwnObject.CompareTo);
```

However, it's not that simple: I get the following compiler message:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<OwnObject>'.
```

I thought I was doing something similar like the `CompareDinosByLength` from [the Microsoft learning website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-8.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `OwnObject` already implements `IComparable` (or `IComparable<OwnObject>`, then simply call the parameterless `List<T>.Sort()` method.

If you pass a method to `Sort` like in your example, then it must be compatible with the [`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1) delegate, which expects two strongly typed parameters. You can use it when `T` is not comparable or the default comparison is not preferable:

```cs
// Custom sorting by name if OwnObject does NOT have a proper IComparable implementation
ownObjectsList.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

**Remark from the question author:**

`ToList().Sort()` makes no sense: it should be:

```
resulting_list = ....ToList();
resulting_list.Sort();
```

Comment: I started like this: `ToList().Sort();`, but this generated the compiler error message "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OwnObject>'".

Comment: `Sort()` is a `void` method so it does not have a return value. Store the result of `ToList` into a variable first, then you can call `Sort` on it. Alternatively, you can use the [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) LINQ extension method that has a return value, which does not mutate the original list but returns a new enumerable instance.

Comment: I've updated your answer accordingly. Sometimes I ask myself why I make such stupid mistakes :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the generic `IComparable<T>` also, then you can refer to that function in the `Sort`.

Even if you rely on the default comparer to call it automatically, you should still use this as it's more efficient.

```cs
public int CompareTo(OwnObject obj)
{
    string s1 = this.Name;
    string s2 = obj.Name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the remark, but that was already done.